# Two Templates in One Envelope with DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

I've been able to successfully start an envelope with a template using the `templateID`, but I'm attempting to generate an envelope with *two* documents inside that both have templates. In the DocuSign website interface it's possible to start a new envelope then "check off" multiple templates to add to the envelope.

I've found the API calls to:

- Start an envelope with a template
- Get a template
- Add a *document* to an envelope

However, there's unfortunately nothing that I can find to add a *template* to a draft envelope once it's been created. The question here, in case it's not obvious, is: what is the API call to generate a new document *from a template* and add it to a pre-existing envelope in `created` status?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an envelope based on multiple templates.  The trick is to use the **[compositeTemplates](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#composite-templates)** optional property of the request.

Back in April 2013 I hosted a webinar focused on templates where I demonstrated 3 different template examples.  They were increasing in complexity leading up to the third, where that last one shows how to combine multiple templates into one envelope.  Here is the Gist for it, which contains PHP code and sample JSON bodies:

https://github.com/Ergin008/DocuSign-REST-API-Webinar-April2013

Here is the JSON for the third example, you'll want to add something similar to your request body:

```
{
    "emailSubject": "DocuSign Templates Webinar - Example 3",
    "emailBlurb": "Example #3 - Composite Templates",
    "status": "sent",
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "templateId": "55A80182-2E9F-435D-9B16-FD1E1C0F9D74"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "1",
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "email": "test@docusign.com",
                                "name": "First Recipient",
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "roleName": "RoleOne"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "2",
                    "templateId": "44D9E888-3D86-4186-8EE9-7071BC87A0DA"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence": "2",
                    "recipients": {
                        "signers": [
                            {
                                "email": "test2@docusign.com",
                                "name": "Recipient 2",
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "roleName": "RoleOne"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that the *sequence* property of the server template can be used to change the order that the template documents show up in the envelope.

Comment: Once again, you're awesome! I'll be testing this out within the next couple of days, but I also heard the same answer back from my DocuSign account manager, so I'll go ahead and mark this one answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To add to Ergin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18259201/1219543).

- You can add a template to an existing envelope using the [applyEnvelopeTemplates](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopetemplates/apply/) api.
- You can add templates to a document in the specified envelope using the [EnvelopeTemplate:applyToDocuments](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopetemplates/applytodocument/) api